# python write german umlaute into a file

Tags: python

I know, this question has been asked million times. But I am still stuck with it. I am using python 2 and cannot change to python 3.

problem is this:

```
>>> w = u"ümlaut"
>>> w
>>> u'\xfcmlaut'
>>> print w
ümlaut
>>> dic = {'key': w}
>>> dic
{'key': u'\xfcmlaut'}
>>> f = io.open('testtt.sql', mode='a', encoding='UTF8')
>>> f.write(u'%s' % dic)
```

then file has:

```
{'key': u'\xfcmlaut'}
```

I need `{'key': 'ümlaut'}` or `{'key': u'ümlaut'}`

What am I missing, I am still noob in encoding decoding things :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want this format particularly, since it won't be valid to read into any other application, but never mind.

The problem is that to write a dictionary to a file, it needs to be converted to a string - and to do that, Python calls `repr` on all its elements.

If you create the output manually as a string, all is well:

```
d = "{'key': '%s'}" % w
with io.open('testtt.sql', mode='a', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    f.write(d)
```

Comment: I am trying to create sql file programmatically that will be imported into mysql db.. let me try your version

Comment: But if you're reading it programmatically, why care about the escaping, since the reading application will be able to deal with it? And why not use a proper interchange format like JSON?

Comment: hm, now I realize, I cannot build dicts manually :/. there is no possibility to build dynamically but still keep the umlauts?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to switch to python3, but since you can't do that, how about converting dictionary to json first before trying to save it into the file.

```
import io
import json
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

w = u"ümlaut"
dic = {'key': w}
f = io.open('testtt.sql', mode='a', encoding='utf8')
f.write(unicode(json.dumps(dic, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')))
```